# Music Controller выравнивается по низу RecyclerView, а не по низу экрана

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: когда запускаю приложение на своем устройстве, низ медиаконтроллера находится там же,  где и низ `RecyclerView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако не совсем понимаю, почему так происходит, ибо я нигде не задаю расположение `MediaController`. Поэтому такой вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы `MediaController` располагался снизу?

**UPD**

Вот слой активности, на котором используется `mediacontroller`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListOfSongsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/songList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="NestedScrolling" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: А что за контейнер вы используете ?

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что все это добро так или иначе находится в ScrollView. Он может не занять все доступное пространство даже с высотой match_parent. Добавьте в разметку к ScrollView атрибут android:fillViewPort="true"

Comment: Обновил вопрос.